# Construir TJSOn para petición en webService

Tags: webservice, delphi

Antes que todo Muchas gracias de antemano, estimados colegas. Espero que me puedan ayudar si es posible o por lo menos orientar. 
El tema es el siguiente: Tengo un servidor del tipo REST en tres capas (Gracias a amigo [SJuan76](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/14311/sjuan76) por aclarármelo) funcionando bien, donde tengo por ejemplo algunos de los tantos procedimientos lo siguiente:

**Del lado del servidor**

```
function TServerParkin.acceptVehiculo(Vehiculo: TVehiculos): TResult;
var
  Datos : TDMDatos;
begin
  try
    try
      Result := Tresult.Create;
      Result.Return_Code:= 0;
      Result.Error_Menssage := '';
      Result.Valor := '';

      if (Vehiculo.Placa.IsEmpty) then
      begin
        Result.Return_Code := -1;
        Result.Error_Menssage := 'La placa es Necesaria para esta operación!';
        Exit;
      end;

      Datos := TDMDatos.Create(nil);

      Datos.Vehiculo.Close;
      Datos.Vehiculo.ParamByName('cod_Cliente').Value;
      Datos.Vehiculo.Open;

      Datos.Vehiculo.Append;
      Datos.VehiculoId_Cliente.AsInteger := Vehiculo.cod_Cliente;
      Datos.VehiculoMarca.AsString := Vehiculo.Marca;
      Datos.VehiculopLaca.AsString := Vehiculo.Placa;

      Datos.Vehiculo.Post;
      Datos.Vehiculo.ApplyUpdates(-1);

    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        Result.Return_Code := -2;
        Result.Error_Menssage := 'Error: ' + e.Message.QuotedString;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

  finally
    if Assigned(Datos) then
      FreeAndNil (Datos);
  end;
end;
```

Esta función es invocada **del lado del cliente** por medio de la siguiente función:

```
function TDataModulo.InsertarVehiculo(Vehiculo: TVehiculos): TResult;
var
  msh: TJSOnMarshal;
  jValue: TJSONValue;
  myUnMarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  try
    RESTRequest.Resource := '/Vehiculo';
    RESTRequest.Method := rmPUT;
    msh := TJSOnMarshal.Create;
    jValue := msh.marshal(Vehiculo);
    RESTRequest.ClearBody;
    RESTRequest.AddBody(jValue.ToString,
      contentTypeFromString('application/json'));
    RESTRequest.Execute;
    myUnMarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create();
    Result := myUnMarshal.Unmarshal(RESTResponse.JSONValue) as TResult;
  finally
    if assigned(myUnMarshal) then
      FreeAndNil(myUnMarshal);

    if assigned(msh) then
      FreeAndNil(msh);
  end;
end;
```

Esta demás indicar que la estructura de datos de TVehiculo es la siguiente;

```
TVehiculos_Clientes = class
    FId_Vehiculo : Integer;
    FId_Cliente : Integer;
    FMarca : String;
    FPlaca : String;
End;
```

Pues en este escenario esto funciona bastante bien, Ahora lo que deseo es enviar otro dato con la información del Usuario que realiza el cambio para el control de modificaciones estaba pensando en algo así:

```
  TUser = Class
      Flogin: String;
      FClave: String;
  End;
```

Por lo tanto las funciones me quedarían de esta forma del lado del servidor, pues pienso que aca no tengo problemas.

```
function TServerParkin.acceptVehiculo(Vehiculo: TVehiculos; User: TUser): TResult;
Var
    Exitoso: Boolean;
Begin
Exitoso:= false;
//VALIDO SI EL USUARIO TEIEN PERMISO PARA MODIFICACION EN LA BASE DE DATOS
try
//TRABAJO CON LA BASE DE DATOS
//Si todo esta bien Exitoso:= True;
Finally
Si éxito:= true;
    Registro el cambio;
End;
end;
```

**En el cliente:**

```
function TDataModulo.InsertarVehiculo(Vehiculo: TVehiculos; User): TResult;
```

Allí es donde no consigo como enviar el dato adicional en forma JSON porque he realizado muchas pruebas pero nada, hice una prueba por Rest debuger enviando el segundo parámetro como un simple texto y solo he logrado de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues realmente, no puedo entender como hacer el equivalante TJSOnMarshal para Delphi.

Si podrían ayudarme, mucho podria agradecer.